# Pug template not rendering in browser while sending fetch get request from browser

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I am working on a small project wherein the data is selected from database datewise.
For the sake of bravity, I am not including all those database related work here.  I simply
dive into the problem area.

I am using:

1. Express and Pug at back end
2. Fetch API at front end.

The browser is Chrome

Code of my front end file - getDates.html - is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Dates</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script>
        window.onload = ()=>{
            document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('click', sendData)

            function sendData(e){
                e.preventDefault()

                const dates = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=date]')
                let data = {}

                for (date of dates){
                    data[date.name]= date.value
                }

                // using fetch to send get request to server 
                fetch(`/${data.sdate}/${data.edate}`, 
                      { method: 'GET',
                        mode: 'no-cors' } )
                        .catch( err => console.log(err)  )
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>Enter Dates</div>
        <form action="">
            <label for="sdate">Start date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate">
            
            <label for="edate">End date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="edate" id="edate">
            <button id="confirm">Confirm</button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code of my back end side index.js file is as under:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// data received from database 
const data = [
    { date : new Date('2021-04-01'), id : 1, amount: 100, remark : 'test1' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-05'), id : 2, amount: 100, remark : 'test2' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-07'), id : 3, amount: 100, remark : 'test3' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-09'), id : 4, amount: 100, remark : 'test4' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-10'), id : 5, amount: 100, remark : 'test5' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-14'), id : 6, amount: 100, remark : 'test6' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-15'), id : 7, amount: 100, remark : 'test7' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-18'), id : 8, amount: 100, remark : 'test8' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-19'), id : 9, amount: 100, remark : 'test9' },
    { date : new Date('2021-04-20'), id : 10, amount: 100, remark : 'test10' }
]


app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/getDates.html')
})


app.get('/:p1/:p2', (req, res)=>{

    // filter data datewise 
    const filtered = data.filter( element =>{
        return element.date >= new Date( `${req.params.p1}` ) && element.date <= new Date( `${req.params.p2}` )
    } )
    

    // prepare data for use with pug template 
    let fData =[]
    fData.push( Object.keys( filtered[0] ).map(x => x.toUpperCase() ) ) 

    for (let line of filtered){
        fData.push( Object.values( line ) )   
    }

    // console.log( fData )  // check data on console -->> upto here it works fine 
    res.render('report', { title: 'Sale data', rows: fData })  // this is not rendered if fetch request is sent 

})

app.listen(port, ()=>  console.log(`Server running on port no: ${port} ...`))
```

Code of my pug file is as under:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        title Report
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css")
    body 
        .tableDiv 
            div #{title}
            table 
                each row in rows 
                    tr 
                        each col in row 
                            td #{col}
```

Code of my CSS file style.css is as under:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    font: bold 12px arial;  /* short-cut ->> weight style size family */
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.wrapper form label {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.wrapper form label, .wrapper form input {
    display:block;
}

.wrapper form button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.tableDiv {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tableDiv div {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: beige;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.tableDiv table, .tableDiv td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableDiv table td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

From the above code it is evident that:

1. There is index.js file which serves css formatted getDates.html file into the browser to get required information.
2. When user inputs start date, end date and press confirm button, the fetch get request is sent to the server.
3. There is no error in browser console when confirm button is pressed.
4. Server receives request and prepares data for use in pug template file, which when console logged, is displayed in console.
   ***This means that application is behaving correctly till this line - 'console.log( fData )' in index.js and here lies the problem.***
5. The pug file report.pug is not rendered to the browser.
6. Interesting part is that when  'http://localhost:5000/2021-04-01/2021-04-10' is directly typed in address bar and pressed
   enter, the pug template is rendered !!!!!!

I can not figure out as to what is happening.  My questions are:

1. Is the fetch request correctly sent to get datewise dynamic result?
2. Is there error on server side which prevents template to render?

I shall be grateful for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the fetch API somewhat

Fetch returns a promise, so you would need to call `then` to access the result.  There is some great documentation about how to use fetch on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Response)

The simplest way to do what you want is probably just assign the target URL like so

```
window.location.pathname = `/${data.sdate}/${data.edate}`
```

This will redirect your user, which I assume is the behavior you were looking for.

Comment: You are right Andrew Breidenbach!  I want that after clicking 'Confirm' button, the user should be able to view data as per dates entered.  Previously, I did this successfully by simply submitting the form.  

But, in order to maintain safety of data on the network, I am required to use Fetch API.  Right, fetch returns a Promise.  

I extensively read MDN for solution but I could not find code in which a Pug Template is rendered in response.  I am still working on that.

In the meantime, if you can throw some light as to how can I use fetch function to get this result.  Thanks. 